# no matching function for call to 'WidgetBridge::WidgetBridge()'

Tags: c++, class, constructor, blynk

I've visited this forum many many many times, but this is my actual first post here. Usually I can find my answer here and I guess I've probably found it this time, but *this* time my knowledge is lacking to understand the solutions given (been learning C++ for the last 2 weeks).

The error I get:

> no matching function for call to 'WidgetBridge::WidgetBridge()'

an extraction of my (rather lengthy) code:

```
class Room {
private:

  //initializer list of internal objects
  WidgetBridge bridge_thermostat;
  WidgetBridge bridge_relay;

public:
  //Constructor of the class:
  Room() : bridge_thermostat(V100), bridge_relay(V107){}

  void initBridges(String authThermostat, String authRelay){
      bridge_thermostat.setAuthToken(authThermostat);
      bridge_relay.setAuthToken(authRelay);
  }

  void receiveCurrentT(float param){
    currentT = param;
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, currentT);
    timer.restartTimer(thermostatTimer );          //reset isDead timer for thermostat
    Blynk.setProperty(V17, "color", BLYNK_GREEN);    //change LED color
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V17, 200);
  }
} livingRoom;

BLYNK_CONNECTED() {
  Blynk.syncAll();
  livingRoom.initBridges("xxx", "xxxx");  //auth of: thermostat, relay
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V10){ livingRoom.receiveCurrentT(param.asFloat());        } //receive currentT from thermostat
```

Based on the answers I've found on this forum it appears that WidgetBridge doens't have its own constructor when called. Based on the answers given I've also tried:

```
public:
    //Constructor of the class:
  Room() : {
    bridge_thermostat = V100;
    bridge_relay = V107;
  }
```

but that rendered the same error. I've continued reading about static fields, constructors, namespaces, etc. but bottomline: I'm stuck and I don't know how to fix this.

Additional info: code is for an esp8266 arduino wifi module which communicates with other esp8266's (relay and thermostat). The communication takes place through 'bridges' which are created using code from the [Blynk app](http://docs.blynk.cc/#widgets-other-bridge).

Thank you for your time!

UPDATE: I've finally found the actual calss widgetbridge itself. And from the mentioned solution I gathered that it has no constructor of itself, but it does..so now I'm really lost. Here's part of the widget class:

```
class WidgetBridge
    : private BlynkWidgetBase
{
public:
    WidgetBridge(uint8_t vPin)
        : BlynkWidgetBase(vPin)
    {}

    void setAuthToken(const char* token) {
        char mem[BLYNK_MAX_SENDBYTES];
        BlynkParam cmd(mem, 0, sizeof(mem));
        cmd.add(mPin);
        cmd.add("i");
        cmd.add(token);
        Blynk.sendCmd(BLYNK_CMD_BRIDGE, 0, cmd.getBuffer(), cmd.getLength()-1);
    }
(....)
};
```

Comment: Your first constructor should not cause that error, but the second one should. The error message should also indicate a location in the source that it refers to. Please share what it is.

Comment: not sure what you're exactly looking for, but here's the full error report:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fol1cplf16iq369/errorResult.txt?dl=0

Comment: `Room() : targetT(20), currentT(20), heatOn(false), maintenanceOn(false) errorOn(false)` this is not the code you're showing.

Answer (score 0):

From the code extract you posted (partial) and the error message(partial too...) , the only reasonable answer is that the WidgetBridge class as no default constructor (i.e. constructor with 0 argument).

Probably because the base class BlynkWidgetBase has no  default constructor as well.

So you get compiler errors on those lines

```
  //initializer list of internal objects
  WidgetBridge bridge_thermostat;
  WidgetBridge bridge_relay;
```

You can either implement a WidgetBride default constructor or instanciate those two variables with the constructor taking a uint8_t parameter :

```
  //initializer list of internal objects
  WidgetBridge bridge_thermostat(3); 
  WidgetBridge bridge_relay(4);
```

3 and 4 to be replaced by whatever value that makes sense, but only you can know that from the code extract